# How to get the id of the parent and the position of an li item

Tags: jquery, html, parent-child, parent

I want to change a nested Navigation by drag and drop and i find a nice plugin. Now i want to store the changes in the database, but unfortually I can't read out the id of the parent element. The second thing what I need is the new position of the dragged li element in the list

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery/interface.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery/inestedsortable-1.0.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($) {
        $('#Hnav, #Nnav').NestedSortable(
            {
                accept: 'sort',
                noNestingClass: "no-children",
                helperclass: 'helper',
                autoScroll: true,
                onChange: function(serialized) {
            onStop : function(){
              $('#output').html($(this).id); // works fine
              $('#output').html($(this).parent().parent().att('id')); // fail
                  $('#output').html(this.closest('li').att('id')); // fail
            },
                nestingPxSpace : '0'
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

---

html

```
<div id="sitemap">
<ul id="Hnav">
  <li id="n1"><a href="contentsite.php?cont=1">Home</a></li>
  <li id="n2" class="sort"><a href="contentsite.php?cont=2">Choir</a>
    <ul class="level2">
      <li id="n4" class="sort"><a href="contentsite.php?cont=3">lkff</a></li>
      <li id="n6" class="sort"><a href="contentsite.php?cont=5">changethis</a></li>
      <li id="n5" class="sort"><a href="contentsite.php?cont=4">History</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

### ...

Any idea? Thank you.

Lara

Comment: in your original you were spelling att, not attr you probably caught it by now.

Comment: @Lara Röpnack I am trying to run ur Jquery but it says onStop : function require name

Answer (score 4):

My guess is you have to wrap `this` with the `$()` syntax if you're calling `parent()` on it:

```
$('#output').html(this.id); // works fine
$('#output').html($(this).parent().parent().attr('id'));
$('#output').html($(this).closest('li').attr('id'));
```

#### Edit:

I have updated the code in response to your comment. jQuery objects do not support `.id`, they must use `.attr('id')`.

Comment: $('#output').html($(this).parent().parent().id); // no error no output
$('#output').html(this.closest('li').attr('id')); // fail
$('#output').html(this.closest('li').id); // fail

Comment: @Lara....your comment still has a bare `this`. You need to wrap it with `$()`...i.e. `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use either:

```
 $('#output').html($(this).parent().parent().attr('id')); // or
 $('#output').html($(this).closest('li').attr('id')); // or
 $('#output').html(this.parentNode.parentNode.id);
```

Comment: $('#output').html(this.parentNode.parentNode.id);
is woks all other fail. I don't understand. I thougt this is exactly the same thing